# How to Use Convolution Theorem to Apply a 2D Convolution on an Image

Tags: image-processing, matlab, fourier-transform, convolution

How do I actually apply the convolution theorem? I have my fourier transformed image matrix, and a Fourier transformed kernel, but how do I actually multiply these together to achieve the intended effect of the kernel? Is it through matrix multiplication or some other method? The dimensions are different though.

Answer (score 1):

You have many great code examples at our community:

- [2D Frequency Domain Convolution Using FFT (Convolution Theorem)](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70775).
- [Kernel Convolution in Frequency Domain - Cyclic Padding](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2774).
- [2D Image Convolution: Spatial Domain vs. Frequency Domain Convolution in the Computational Complexity Sense](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/42567).
- [Applying Image Filtering (Circular Convolution) in Frequency Domain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/38542).
- [Applying 2D Image Convolution in Frequency Domain with Replicate Border Conditions in MATLAB](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70908).
- [How to Zero Pad in Order to Perform Filtering in the Fourier (Frequency) Domain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/56407)?
- [Replicate MATLAB's `conv2()` in Frequency Domain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74803).

The last 2 have a specific code to do image filtering in frequency domain.

Comment: Thank you. From reading those posts, I understand that you have to pad the two matrices with 0s, and then element multiplying them. I am doing this manually instead of with code, as I do not have any coding knowledge, so am I understanding it right?

Comment: Indeed. You need to pad them both to the same size according to your needs.

Comment: @botman, Anything missing in my answer? Could you tell me what's missing in order to accept it?